# singular perturbation to find a composite expansion

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Determine the first two terms in the inner and outer expansions for the following problem on the interval $0\leq x\leq1$,

$(1+\epsilon)x^2\frac{du}{dx}=\epsilon[(1-\epsilon)xu^2-(1+\epsilon)x+u^3+2\epsilon u^2]$, $u(1)=1$

where $0<\epsilon \ll 1.$ Construct the composite expansion.

Comment: I need to apply the singular perturbation analysis to solve this problem, but I am stuck with the inner solution at x=0. Note that x^2 in front of the derivative will cause the singularity

Comment: Hey David, feel free to ask any question you might have concerning my solution. If you feel unsure how to finish the question, just let me know and I'll give you some more tips.

Comment: Hi Cyclone, thanks so much for your explanations. But I have not fully understood your solution. For inner solution,why $u\sim 1/x$, and how you determine the rescaling $x=\epsilon^{1/3}y$? and $u \sim \epsilon^{-1/3}v$? Looking forward to your reply.

Comment: In fact, there was a mistake, thanks for asking. It's really $u\sim \epsilon /x$, which can be read off from the outer solution. Then the scalings chance slightly. I have edited my answer. Please see below.

Comment: Hi Cyclone,Thanks so much for your detailed calculation. I got it now. Plus, I feel $A$ should be equal to 1, right? This is just some minor problem. Thanks again. I really appreciate it.

Comment: No problem, it would be nice if you accept my answer.

Comment: Hi Cyclone, could you please help me with another question. I want to use Lindstedt-Poincare method or multiple scale method to find a uniformly valid first approximation to the equation

$\frac{d^2u}{dt^2}-\epsilon (1-u^2)\frac{du}{dt}+u=0$, and show that for a large class of initial conditions, the solution approaches a limit cycle as $t\rightarrow \infty$. I tried Lp method, but could not obtain a good result. Can you help me with it?

Comment: I'm happy to try and answer that question if you post it as a separate question here on StackExchange. And don't forget to accept my answer if you're happy with it. What makes you think that A should be equal to 1? If I haven't made a mistake then for matching we need to have $A=1/3$.

Answer (score 0):

We will proceed as follows: compute the outer solution, from that determine the scaling for the inner solution, rescale $x$ appropriately, determine the inner solution, then match (may also do so along the way). Then write down composite expansion.

For the **outer expansion**, we simply insert $u(x)=u_0(x)+\epsilon u_1(x)+o(\epsilon)$. Then we find $u_0 = cst. = 1$ by $u(1)=1$. At order epsilon, we find  $\frac{\mathrm{d}u_1}{\mathrm{d}x}=1/x^2$. Hence 
$$u(x)=1+\epsilon (1-1/x) + o(\epsilon)$$,

**Inner expansion**:
**EDIT** - There was a mistake in the original scaling. In fact it is $u \sim \epsilon/x$, as can be read off from the outer solution. The two dominant terms are still the LHS and $\epsilon u^3$ (try out other dominant balances, it will lead to contradictions because terms you neglected are actually larger than the ones you kept). But now the resulting scaling for $x$ is $x\sim \epsilon$ and $u\sim 1$. Define $x=\epsilon y$. We do not need to rescale $u$ now. Plugging this into the equation and dividing by $\epsilon$ gives the equation in the inner region:
$$
(1+\epsilon) y^2 \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}y} = (1-\epsilon) \epsilon y u^2 - (1+\epsilon)\epsilon y + u^3 + 2\epsilon u^2
$$
Now, to find the inner solution, expand again $u=u_o+\epsilon u_1+o(\epsilon)$. Then, as it has to be by virtue of our rescaling, the zeroth order equation is 
$$y^2\frac{\mathrm{d}u_o}{\mathrm{d}y} = u_o^3,$$
 whose solution is $u_o(y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{B+2/y}}$, where $B$ is a constant. In the limit of $y\to \infty$, matching this with the outer solution, this means that $B=1$, i.e. 
$$u_o(y)=\sqrt{y}/\sqrt{2+y}$$.
 At the next order, there is a nice cancellation and the ODE reads: 
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}u_1}{\mathrm{d}y} = \frac{3}{y(2+y)}u_1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{y(2+y)^3}},$$ 
which can be solved using an integrating factor as follows. Multiply by $\exp(-\int_y 3/(y(2+y))\mathrm{d}y)=\left(\frac{2+y}{y}\right)^{3/2} = u_o^{-3} $
Then the derivative term and the $u_1$ term become a total derivative which can be integrated to give 
$$u_1(y)=u_o(y)^3\left(C+\frac{1}{y}\right) = \left(\frac{y}{2+y}\right)^{3/2} \left(C+\frac{1}{y}\right),$$
where $C$ is a constant.

**Matching:**
In case you haven't seen it done, I sketch how to do asymptotic matching. To match inner and outer solution, we need to take the limit $x\to 0$ and $y\to \infty$, such that $\epsilon \ll x \ll 1$. This is conveniently done by letting $x= \epsilon^\alpha \eta$, $y=\epsilon^{1-\alpha} \eta$, where $\alpha \in (0,1)$ and $\eta = \mathrm{ord}(1)$. Then one gets

$$u_{outer} = 1+ \epsilon - \epsilon^{1-\alpha} \frac{1}{\eta} + \dots,$$

while
$$ u_{inner} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+2/y}} + \epsilon \frac{1}{(1+2/y)^{3/2}} (C+1/y) \\ \, \, = 1- \frac{1}{\eta} \epsilon^{1-\alpha} + \epsilon C + (1-3C) \epsilon^{2-\alpha} \frac{1}{\eta} +\dots   $$

The $\mathrm{ord}(1)$ and $\mathrm{ord}(\epsilon^{1-\alpha})$ terms agree automatically because we matched $B$ along the way and because of the scaling we used to find the inner solution. This is an important consistency check. Then order $\epsilon$ tells us that $C=1$. So finally, 
$$ u_{outer}(x) = 1+\epsilon\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)+o(\epsilon) $$
and
$$ u_{inner}(y) = \frac{\sqrt{y}}{\sqrt{2+y}} + \left(\frac{y}{2+y}\right)^{3/2} \left(1+\frac{1}{y}\right) + o(\epsilon) $$

**Composite expansion:**
A uniformly valid composite expansion (meaning one which is valid in the whole domain to some order) is obtained by adding inner and outer solutions and substracting the inner limit of the outer solution (or the outer limit of the inner solution). In our case, this is particularly simple and we find:

$$ u_c(x) = u_o(x) + u_i(x/\epsilon) - \underbrace{u_{i,o}(x)}_{u_o(x)} = u_i(x/\epsilon) =  \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{2\epsilon}{x}}} + \epsilon \frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{2\epsilon}{x}\right)^{3/2}} \left(1+\frac{\epsilon}{x}\right) + o(\epsilon)$$

If you don't agree with a result or you don't understand a step, please just ask.

Comment: In my opinion, when we impose the given boundary condition $u(1)=1$ on the outer solution, we might have $u_{outer}(1)=1$. Thus $A=1$. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that should be correct. So I agree that $A$ should be equal to $1$. I think I have found the mistake. It seems I'm not allowed to look at the order $\epsilon^{2-\alpha}$ because in the outer solution, at order $\epsilon^2$, I might get terms of that order. Therefore $A=C=1$ is consistent.